# Pyside2 how to open the dialog but not always on top

Tags: python, pyside2

I create a main frame and a pushbutton ,

and let button clicked to open a dialog , but the dialog always on top ,

I try to used setWindowsFlag but not work.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QTabWidget,QWidget
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMessageBox,QFileDialog,QErrorMessage
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class UI_Test20(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test202):
        Test202.setObjectName("Test202")
        Test202.resize(100,100)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test202)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb.setText('push button!')
        Test202.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.retranslateUi(Test202)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test202)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test202):
        Test202.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Test202", "MainWindow", None, -1))

    def btnClicked(self):
        ui = Ui_Dialog1(self)
        ui.show()

class Test20(QMainWindow, UI_Test20) :

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Test20, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

and the dialog code

```
class Ui_Dialog1(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.p = parent
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog1):
        Dialog1.setObjectName("Dialog1")
        Dialog1.resize(333, 173)
```

main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Test20(None)
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the main window is the parent of the `QDialog`, so it must be removed, but if that is done, the garbage collector will delete it, so the `QDialog` member of the class must be made:

```
def btnClicked(self):
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog1()
    self.ui.show()
```

**Plus:** the correct thing is not to modify the design so I move the connection and the slot associated with the clicked button `pb` and if we want it to close when the window closes we overwrite the `closeEvent()` method:

```
class Test20(QMainWindow, UI_Test20):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Test20, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

    def btnClicked(self):
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog1()
        self.ui.show()

    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ui.close()
        QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! another question ,  I  close the  main frame and this opened dialog should close too , should I write code to close diloag or not ?

Comment: yes, it overwrites the closeEvent method and in that part you close the dialog

Comment: Thanks I will try~

Comment: I added that part to my answer.

Comment: if I press the top right close button ,  something work in dialog still working ,(ex QtCore.QTimer()) , how can I avoid it ?

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: @RelaxZeroC Do not add more questions, SO is a place for a single post for each question. Create a new question.

Comment: OK! I will post a new one